# Grunt Task That Can be Run With Non-Option Arguments

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to write a grunt task with an api ***identical*** to that of the unix mv command.

I'd like to be able to call it with `grunt mv path/to/old/file path/to/new/file`.

I was hoping I'd be able to do it by accessing node's process.argv, however when I call the task using this API, grunt tries to treat `path/to/old/file` as another task I'm trying to run, throws an error that `Warning: Task "path/to/old/file" not found. Use --force to continue.` and exits.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `--options` parameter http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#options.

So you can call it with `grunt mv --from=path/to/old/file --to=path/to/new/file`.

Comment: That's my current, and the obvious implementation. I'm trying to bypass the need for --from= and --to=.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought the obvious would be to go with grunt mv:path/to/old/file:path/to/new/file, as described in http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#basic-tasks.

Comment: Ah, that is a good suggestion. The colon-separated approach would definitely save some typing from --to= and --from=, but I would still love to find a way to mimic the command line `mv`'s api if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments to your tasks by separating them with ":", e.g.

```
grunt mv:path/to/old/file:path/to/new/file
```

It's **definitely** not ideal though. Inside your task you can get their values with `this.args`. See https://github.com/Grunt-generate/grunt-generate/blob/master/tasks/generate.js
for an example. And here's the API doc: http://gruntjs.com/api/inside-tasks

Answer (score 0):

You should use [process.argv](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) from de documentation:

> An array containing the command line arguments. The first element will
>   be 'node', the second element will be the name of the JavaScript file.
>   The next elements will be any additional command line arguments.

In your case:

File: **mv.js**

```
console.log(process.argv[2]);
console.log(process.argv[3]);
```

Then if you run: **node mv.js path/to/old/file path/to/new/file**

This will output:

```
path/to/old/file
path/to/new/file
```

Comment: This would work if I weren't using Grunt, but I am, and I want to keep this task within Grunt. You can't get past Grunt's initialization when you call it as you suggest. Grunt interprets path/to/old/file as a task, and complains that it cant find a task by that name. It looks like if I run it with --force, I maybe able to get into the task and use node's process.argv, however I'd like to avoid having devs need to type --force for this task.